# Understanding New Javascript Ternary Condition Convention

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I don't know this condition convention in JS(!params?.q). I know the ternary condition but I don't understand this. Can anyone provide insights on this or what should I learn to understand similar conventions?

JS Code Block

```
 if (!params?.q) {// I don't understand a '?' without a ternary //condition
      setSkipFirstRender(false);
      setSort({
        name: PersonEnum.keys.displayName,
        dir: PersonEnum.sortOrder.asc,
      });
}
```

Comment: This isn't a ternary condition it's an optional chaining parameter [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?.` operator is the optional chaining operator, sometimes also called the Elvis operator.

Despite both using the `?` character, the optional chaining operator and ternary statements serve two different purposes.

Normally if you were to access `params.q` and `params` was null or undefined, an error would be thrown. What the optional chaining operator allows you to do is safely attempt to access the `q` property without an error being thrown. In this case, if `params` were null or undefined, `params?.q` would evaluate to `undefined`.

Essentially this is equivalent to checking `if(!(params && params.q))`.

You can read more about the optional chaining operator at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining